# IOS Production Release Error:-- Error - Certificate doesn't match profile: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, phonegap

I can successfully build the IPA file for testing but whilst building for the app store release it gives the error:

> " Error - Certificate doesn't match profile: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching"

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple causes for this problem. I can only guesses based on the very limited info you provided.

Try to re-export the developer certificate from your keychain, which would be a p12 file and ensure that you have create a valid Distribution( not Developer ) profile created for your app in the developers console.

Comment: I have used the App_Store_Dist.mobileprovision and p12 certificate while building but it shows the mentioned error. But for testing purpose App_Development.mobileprovision and p12 certificate and it is successfully build

Answer (score 0):

It seems for testing developer certificates been used.

Checkout **Adhoc certificates and provisioning profiles** and use **App Store** provisioning profiles.